# why when i send data to another activity and in other activity i want get it project stop?

Tags: android, android-intent

this is some code of my first class

```
   result = "ok&rent##18##20000000##80##500000##2##shofaj --- kaf parkeet ....##http://www.studentuniverse.com/student-blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/iStock_000017716462Medium-e1374689640445.jpg##http://www.studentuniverse.com/student-blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/apps.jpeg## " ;
            String []respon = result.split("&");

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show_item_select.class);
                in.putExtra("url", respon[1]);
                in.putExtra("code", Select_Data.get_id());
                in.putExtra("itm",itm);
                in.putExtra("urls", urls);
                startActivity(in);
```

this is some code of my secend class

```
   String s= getIntent( ).getStringExtra("url");
            code = getIntent().getStringExtra("code");
            itm =getIntent().getIntExtra("itm",0);
            urls = s.split("##");
            urls_all = getIntent().getStringExtra("urls");
```

when progrom go to secend class and read first line program stoped and show page that write Source not found and this is topic :

```
    ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2032.

DalvikVM[localhost:8602]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended)   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2032    
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2135 
        ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 140    
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1237  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 137 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4921    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1038 
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 805 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
    Thread [<11> Binder_3] (Running)    
    Thread [<12> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
    Thread [<13> AsyncTask #2] (Running)    
    Thread [<14> AsyncTask #3] (Running)
```

anyone khnow why this happen ?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the entire stack trace.  The one line you've posted isn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try and change

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
```

for

```
String s = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");
```

It's also a good practice to check that the *extras* bundle is initialized, like this.-

```
String s = null;
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    s = extras.getString("url");
}
```

Finally, you should consider using constants for your extras names, just to make sure you don't have *typo issues* in the future.

Comment: dont work..!! i write string s .. in program and when read first line(bundle ex..) same error show ..